# How to add marquee animation to icon titles on Bottom Navigation View?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I was wondering if there is a way that makes the **bottom navigation bar icon titles** to scroll like **marquee**. I have seen some apps like that and tried to find some ways but couldn't find any. so if anyone could help me i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There is the simplest solution. Works on Material Components versions 1.0.0 - 1.2.0-alpha02.

```
fun BottomNavigationView.findAllLabels(): Sequence<TextView> {
    return sequence {
        children.forEach { bottomNavigationChild ->
            if (bottomNavigationChild is ViewGroup) {
                bottomNavigationChild.children.forEach {
                    val smallLabel = it.findViewById<TextView>(
                        com.google.android.material.R.id.smallLabel
                    )
                    yield(smallLabel)
                    val largeLabel = it.findViewById<TextView>(
                        com.google.android.material.R.id.largeLabel
                    )
                    yield(largeLabel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Your BottomNavigationView
bottomNavigationView.findAllLabels().forEach {
    it.apply {
        ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE
        setSingleLine(true)
        // For infinite loop, comment if it's not required
        marqueeRepeatLimit = -1
    }
}
```